# Recursive find that will append directory name to any file

Tags: linux

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I need a way to append the parent directory name to any file in any path.

An example current directory tree

```
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture1.jpg  
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture2.jpg  
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture3.jpg
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture1.jpg
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture2.jpg
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture3.jpg
```

The goal

```
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture1.800x600.jpg  
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture2.800x600.jpg   
/Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture3.800x600.jpg  
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture1.4096x2160.jpg
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture2.4096x2160.jpg
/RockClimbing/SouthAfrica/TableMountain/4096x2160/Picture3.4096x2160.jpg
```

I have found some examples of this but the users all have set directory depths unfortunately I have files at many different levels.

```
find dir -name *.jpg -exec rename -nv -- 's|/(.*)/(.*)$|/$1/$1.jpg|' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first capture group is matching everything before the last `/`, not just the last directory name. Use `/([^/]*)/` instead of `/(.*)/` so it won't match across `/` delimiters. You're also not splitting up the filename into the name and extension, so you're not inserting the directory name between them.

```
find dir -name *.jpg -exec rename -nv -- 's|([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$|$1/$2.$1.jpg|' {} +
```

Comment: find /path -name *.jpg -exec rename -nv -- 's|/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$|/$1/$2.$1.jpg|' {} +

Comment: Had no affect on the files

Comment: The `-n` option means not to rename anything, just show what would happen.

Comment: Thanks for the help Barmar, running the entire command yeilds no output or affect, if i run just the find section and exclude everything after and including -exec it displays all .jpg files as axpected

Comment: What does `rename -nv -- 's|/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.jpg$|/$1/$2.$1.jpg|' /Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture1.jpg` show?

Comment: No output, if I "ls -al /Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture1.jpg" it displays correctly

Comment: How about something really simple: `rename -nv 's/1/X/' /Hawaii/Surfing/800x600/picture1.jpg`

Comment: I tried it on my machine and my answer works. What does `rename --help` show?

Comment: no output on the simplified rename command, rename --help
call: rename from to files...   this is on RHEL6.5

Comment: You're not using the perl version of `rename`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I'll get that installed.